# Calling a Myrange Function in a Sub

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I put together a `regex` function that will remove all whitespace from a column, and when I use it on a sheet I just have to type in `=simplecellregex()` then I run that in the new column against all of the entries. The reason I am doing it this way is because `TRIM()` does not work always so I looked for a way that did.

```
Function simpleCellRegex(Myrange As Range) As String

    Dim Regex As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    Dim strOutput As String

    strPattern = "\s+$"

        If strPattern <> "" Then
            strInput = Myrange.Value
            strReplace = ""

        With Regex
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If Regex.Test(strInput) Then
            simpleCellRegex = Regex.Replace(strInput, strReplace)
        Else
            simpleCellRegex = strInput
        End If
    End If
End Function



Sub regex1()

Column.Add
Range("D2").Value = simpleCellRegex(Myrange, String)

End Sub
```

So this was the setup so that whenever I get workbooks I just click the column I want the function to run on and it runs the regex and spits it out the the column next to it. The plan is to make this a macro so I can just add a button on the excel menu ribbon and make this regex easy to run.

Comment: TRIM isn't intended for removing _all_ whitespace. And is there a question? It would help if you made it very clear what the question is and the problem you are having with implementing it.

Comment: What is the question? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Aneta The sub call does not work at all. It wont take my range and spit out the function based on a macro button

Comment: And your function expects one argument which is a range. You are passing 2 arguments when you call it. And the second one you are passing may confuse the compiler even if your function expected two, as your are passing a variable called String which is also a datatype.

Comment: Myrange.Value is going to generate an array not a string so your regex will not work as is. You will need a way to replace all occurences within the range (which isn't a single cell). Using an entire column is also horribly inefficient.

Comment: @QHarr I am sorry I dont ask questions often on this site, I am just trying to get a macro that will run the function. I know the function works because I can just use the =simplecellregex in a cell. I want to make it so I can just click a column and click the macro and have the macro do it all instead of me having the type that into the cell. The sub is where the issue is. I dont understand the arguments and range because I dont use VBA ever. This is literally my first time.

Comment: And your regex is basically a RTRIM. See RTRIM https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/ltrim-rtrim-and-trim-functions

Comment: @user7823345 I don't mean to sound rude. I hope I didn't. I am trying to give some pointers. There are alot of things to address in the code shown.

Comment: @QHarr you arent rude at all, I get you are trying to help and I appreciate it.

Comment: I think maybe you mean a single cell is the range argument if you are calling this from a cell. An UDF (a user defined function) can only return something to the cell it is called from. It cannot impact on other cells. If you are intending on implementing this for more than one cell by calling the function from code you are going to need to make some changes as mentioned above.

Comment: REGEX seems an inefficient way to just remove whitespace at the end of a line.

Comment: Also, a REGEX whitespace character does NOT match the NBSP, which is sometimes a problem in data imported from the web or html document.

Comment: Would you guys recommend I scrap this function and write a RTRIM sub? Never used RTRIM before, didnt know it was a thing. But I do know TRIM didnt work when I was looking to remove all whitespace from entries in a column.

Comment: RTRIM will not remove all whitespace. Only from the right hand side which is what your regex is doing.

Comment: What do you mean by "Not Working".  The worksheet function TRIM will remove trailing and leading spaces, along with duplicate spaces within a string (leaving a single space).  And your regex will only remove trailing spaces (along with trailing tab characters and a few other things that are not usually in a string).  So if that is the only difference between the two, then you are OK.  If not, there is something about your data that needs investigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT:

Use the following if you want to select a range and then press a button

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub RemoveEndWhiteSpace()
    Dim arr(), i As Long, myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Selection
    If myRange.Columns.Count > 1 Or myRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If myRange.Count = 1 Then
        myRange = RTrim$(myRange.Value)
        Exit Sub
    Else
        arr = myRange.Value
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            arr(i, 1) = RTrim$(arr(i, 1))
        Next i
        myRange = arr
    End If
End Sub
```

To output to a different column:

```
myRange.Offset(, 1) = arr '<==use offset to put result in a different column e.g. one to the right
```

---

Example run of the last bit of code tied to a button (where macro is set to all open workbooks btw)

[image: Test]

---

### tl;dr;

If you want to click on a column and trailing white space be removed something like the following. This uses a worksheet event of when you select a column to run the sub. The sub checks how many cells are populated in the column and works with those.

`Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange` would go in the code pane for the sheet you are wanting to do the replacement on.

`.UsedRange` is not always the most reliable method.

The sub it calls would go in a standard module. I suspect there are more efficient ways to do this to be honest but thought I would have a quick play.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count = Columns(1).Cells.Count And Target.Columns.Count = 1 Then
        'MsgBox "running"
        RemoveEndWhiteSpace Intersect(Target, Me.UsedRange)
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub RemoveEndWhiteSpace(ByVal myRange As Range)
    Dim arr(), i As Long
    If myRange.Count = 1 Then
        myRange = RTrim$(myRange.Value)
        Exit Sub
    Else
        arr = myRange.Value
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            arr(i, 1) = RTrim$(arr(i, 1))
        Next i
        myRange = arr
    End If
End Sub
```

More reliable for used range of column would be:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count = Columns(1).Cells.Count And Target.Columns.Count = 1 Then
       ' MsgBox "running"
        Dim lastRow As Long, myRange As Range
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Target.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        Set myRange = Range(Cells(1, Target.Column), Cells(lastRow, Target.Column))
        RemoveEndWhiteSpace myRange
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Comment: See the last bit of code. You can associate that with a button you place on the ribbon.